# How do I show an example of a file in latex?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, examples, files

I need to write an example of a file format.
I want to do something like this:
[image]

The text inside the square is something I'll write inside latex and represents how a certain kind of file is made, it's not the content of a real file on my file system. 
I tried looking up online but I only came across results showing how to import verbatim the content of a file.

I'm also interested in putting the caption after the image.

The text I'll write will be made of file formats and algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the `listings` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,frame=single}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Your caption text}, label=labeltext, captionpos=b]
.i 4
.o 1
-10- 1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know how can I replace the word "Listing" under the figure with another word, like "Figure"?